# How to trigger a Glue job from another Glue job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

Is it possible to trigger a glue job(pyspark) from another glue job(pyspark) using boto3.

Everything seems to be working fine(no syntax or code errors) except the boto3 method

```
glue_client.start_job_run()
```

Tested the similar code in Lambda and it's working fine but In my case I need to use it from glue.

My Glue jobs need to exchange some parameters, so I'm trying to start the other job using the above method while passing the required parameters as arguments to the next job.

I even tried the Glue workflows, Sent the required parameters via Lambda to the workflow. But the jobs in the workflow are not able to read the workflow parameters.

```
glue_client.get_workflow_run_properties(Name=workflow_name, RunId=workflow_run_id)["RunProperties"]
```

My questions is, Am I using the boto3 glue client wrong. Is it supposed to be used only in python shell jobs and not with spark jobs??

Code snippet of starting a glue job from another glue job

```
# Trigger audit glue job
# Declare boto3 glue client
glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
inputParams = {
        "--JobName" : args["JOB_NAME"],
        "--JobId" : args['JOB_RUN_ID'],
        "--redshift_database" : redshift_database
        "--redshift_table_schema" : redshift_table_schema
        "--TableName" : redshift_table,
        "--Last_executed_time" : start_time,
        "--No_of_souce_records" : count_of_souce_records,
        "--No_of_target_records" : count_of_target_records,
        "--Records_updated" : count_of_updated_records
    }
    
print("Triggering audit glue job")

audit_job = glue_client.start_job_run(JobName = 'audit_populate', Arguments = inputParams)
```

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: Could you use AWS Glue Triggers?

Comment: No, the task is to trigger the other job by passing some 'parameters' or 'arguments' as well. @RobertKossendey

Comment: Have a look at it now @Marcin

Comment: @RaviTejaSurla I don't think the properties are passed correctly. What do you see in the job properties on the started job run of audit_populate once it is started?

Comment: Can you try something simple with a workflow like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/workflow-run-properties-code.html and keep adding params you require?